# No security level slide bar in Java control panel

Tags: java, security, applet

I am unable to configure Java security settings using the Java Control Panel. With the latest Java update I can no longer run simple applets. Instructions say to reset security settings. All instructions refer to a slide bar in the Security tab. All I have is a pull down menu for certificates. Please help. I am using Windows 7.Java Control Panel version 7 update 5.

Comment: Link to a screenshot of what you see.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been [identified by Oracle](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_securityslider.xml).
You'll have to <strike>totally reinstall java</strike> uninstall the old conflicting versions.

Answer (score 0):

with new versions of JRE, you don't have the security level slider (medium, high, very high) now instead you have a radio button for high and very high. Tu run your applet, it must have a proper manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: some text
Implementation-Version: 1.1
Built-By: root
Application-Name: some text
Created-By: Apache Maven
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *.somedomain.com
Implementation-Vendor-Id: some text
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_24
Permissions: all-permissions
Specification-Title: some text
Specification-Version: 1.1
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Codebase: *
```

use:

```
jar cfm something.jar manifest.txt *
```

last but most important sign your applet using a certificate.

if you do all the above you should be able to run your applet in IE only as chrome and Firefox no longer support the Java browser plugin